# scons detecting dependency cycle

Tags: scons

I have scons picking up a very odd dependency cycle. It goes something like this:

I have an object_file used in some_library which is used by some_executable in directory Fred/Jim and scons fails to buld, saying it has found this dependency cycle:

object_file -> some_library -> some_executable -> Fred/Jim -> Fred -> . -> object_file

for pretty much every object in that library, but not, as far as I can see, for every reference to that library.

More confusingly, we build this for both aix and solaris architectures, and only the solaris build does this, the aix build is fine.

I'm in the middle of migrating our build system, so it's probably something I changed recently, but I'm unsure as to where to look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, OK, I found it.

It's due to the subtle difference in python between

```
a = ('string')
```

and

```
a = ('string', )
```

The former produces a tuple of characters :-(